# Is there a difference between a picture of me and a picture of mine?

Tags: grammar

Is there a difference between a picture of me and a picture of mine?
As far as I know, a picture of mine is correct. I wonder if we can use 'a picture of me' in a particular context.

Answer (score 15):

> "Picture of me"

You are the subject of the picture. The picture shows you.

> "Picture of mine"

You own the picture. Or you took the picture. Probably you are not the subject, but you could be.

Comment: +1 I wondered what the answer might be but I am thrilled to know how simple it was to comprehend! Kudos!